# Adding @Transactional causes "collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced"

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am upgrading a working project from Spring2+Hibernate3 to Spring3+Hibernate4. Since HibernateTemplate and HibernateDAOSupport have been retired, I did the following

Before (simplified)

```
public List<Object> loadTable(final Class<?> cls)
{
    Session s = getSession(); // was calling the old Spring getSession
    Criteria c = s.createCriteria(cls);
    List<Object> objects = c.list();
    if (objects == null)
    {
        objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    closeSession(s);
    return objects;
}
```

Now (simplified)

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<Object> loadTable(final Class<?> cls)
{
    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria c = s.createCriteria(cls);
    List<Object> objects = c.list();
    if (objects == null)
    {
        objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return objects;
}
```

I also added the transaction annotation declaration to Spring XML and removed this from Hibernate properties

```
 "hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext"
```

The @Transactional annotation seems to have worked as I see this in the stacktrace

```
at com.database.spring.DatabaseDAOImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7d20ef95.loadTable(<generated>)
```

During initialization, the changes outlined above seem to work for a few calls to the loadTable function but when it gets around to loading an entity with a parent, I get the "collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced" error. Since I have not touched any other code that sets/gets parents or children and am only trying to fix the DAO method, and the query is only doing a sql SELECT, can anyone see why the code got broken?

The problem seems similar to [Spring transaction management breaks hibernate cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774206/spring-transaction-management-breaks-hibernate-cascade)

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely problem of Spring, but rather issue with your entity handling / definition. When you are using `deleteOrphans` on a relation, the underlying `PersistentSet` **MUST NOT** be removed from the entity itself. You are allowed only to modify the set instance itself. So if you are trying to do anything clever within your entity setters, that is the cause.

Also as far as I remember there are some issues when you have `deleteOrphans` on both sides of the relation and/or load/manipulate both sides within one session.

---

Btw. I don't think `"hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext"` is necessary. In our project, this is the only configuration we have:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder() {
    return ((LocalSessionFactoryBuilder) new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(
            dataSourceConfig.dataSource()).scanPackages(ENTITY_PACKAGES).
            setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true").
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dataSourceConfig.dialect()).
            setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none"));
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactoryBuilder().buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I've been reading a host of blog posts where setting the parent entity is identified as the cause for this error. There is indeed a lot of "funky" entity generation in the project but I don't want to touch it without knowing why this was not a problem with HibernateTemplate. But I'll look again and report back. Btw, I did remove the "ThreadLocalSessionContext" from the hibernate props.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Session Management. The same block of transactional code was being called by other modules that were doing their own session handling. To add to our woes, some of the calling modules were Spring beans while others were written in direct Hibernate API style. This disorganization was sufficient work to keep us away from moving up to Hibernate 4 immediately.

Moral of the lesson (how do you like that English?): Use a consistent DAO implementation across the entire project and stick to a clearly defined session and transaction management strategy.